# System.TypeLoadException:'Method 'CommitTransactionAsync' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.Storage.Internal.InMemoryTransactionManager'

Tags: c#, .net

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Method 'CommitTransactionAsync' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory.Storage.Internal.InMemoryTransactionManager' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory, Version=3.1.21.0, Culture=neral, PublicKeyToken=ad' does not have an implementation.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just updated my `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory` to version 5.0.10 and it worked.
( Current Proj running on netcore3.1 ).